# Application of Neighborhood search in CPLEX

Tags: search, optimization, cplex, neighbours

I implemented a mixed integer problem directly in CPLEX.
My problem is that it takes to long for my purposes to find a optimum solution.
I set a time limit oF 10 minutes. So after 10 minutes I get a feasible solution but I don´t how far it is away from the optimum.
Now I read about a Variable Neighborhood Search, which makes optimization a lot faster while "promising" a near optimum solution.
As far as I know, CPLEX does not directly offer VNS, but it is able to perform a Relaxed Induced Neighborhood Search (RINS). Two question about this:

1. How do I apply it?
2. Does it have the same effect as the VNS (find near optimal solutions in short time)

Thanks a lot!
Sincerely

Comment: "I don´t how far it is away from the optimum" Cplex reports a gap that is a bound on how far the integer solution is removed from the optimal solution.

Comment: Firstly, CPLEX has RINS built-in as one of its heuristics that gets used anyway during its B&B search. It is just one of a number of such heuristics that are used, including local branching, probing, diving etc which typically speed up convergence on a range of large problems. Look at the parameters and you will see a parameter for the RINS heuristic frequency - it is 'on' by default and happens at a frequency that CPLEX decides based on its own internal analysis while solving your problem

Comment: Thank you very much for quick answers! @Erwin Kalvelagen: What I don´t really understand. Maybe the question is studpid, but I have to ask: If normally the finding of the optimal solution would have taken like 5 hours and I set the time limit to 10 minutes. How can CPLEX know how far the solution is away from the optimum?

Comment: It is a little bit more subtle. Cplex does not know the distance from the optimal solution. But it does know that it is not further away than the gap. This gap is getting smaller during the run. That is a unique capability of branch and bound methods. I watch this gap like a hawk.

Comment: Ahh okay, thats nice! I will have a look at my gaps tomorrow and decide whats next :)

Answer (score 1):

For various types of neighbourhood search, you are largely on your own in that there isn't much that works well built into any of the big commercial solvers. However at one level it is really very easy to experiment with it.

Assume that you already have a feasible solution to your problem. Then you can create a new smaller problem by re-solving your original problem but with most of the variables in your model fixed to the values from your known solution - you might choose to fix 90%, 95% or 99% of your variable values. That will leave a much smaller number of variables for the solver to find values and it will typically find an optimal solution to your 'sub-problem' in a few seconds, and it can sometimes find a better set of values for those variables that you didn't fix or freeze in your model. You can safely replace the values of those variables in your current best known solution with their new values because you are guaranteed that those values are compatible with the rest of your solution. Then choose a different set of variables to fix/freeze and do it again, and keep repeating this process.

The art and craft of making this work well for *your* problem is how you choose which variables to fix/freeze and which to re-solve. The more variables that you leave un-fixed, the larger the 'neighborhood' around your previous solution and the more opportunities there are for finding an improvement, but each sub-problem takes longer to solve. There will be some sweet spot of sub-problem size that works well, but you will have to experiment to see what works. Similarly it helps to leave related variables un-fixed in your sub-problem. You could just choose them at random and the process will still converge but it will be slower; it is better to think about your problem structure, e.g. relax and re-solve one day's worth of variables in a schedule, or the variables for one or more resource, or whatever. Again it depends on your problem.

Comment: Just to add I found an interesting paper that describes this approach in some detail here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0305054814001816